# How to pass shell script arguments to a oozie

Tags: mysql, shell, hadoop, oozie

I have a shell script to import data from `MySQL to hdfs` i.e `sqoop` shell script. I want to use `oozie` to schedule the sqoop import jobs.

The script has the following `sqoop query`

```
sqoop import --connect ${domain}:${port}/${database} --username ${username} --password ${password} --query "select * from ${table} where  \$CONDITIONS" -m 1  --hive-import --hive-database ${hivedatabase} --hive-table ${table}  --target-dir  /user/hive/warehouse/${hivedatabase}.db/${table}
```

I have all these arguments in another `.sh` file. Now I want to pass these arguments in the workflow.xml file. Or should I pass these arguments in the job.properties file.

The argument `${table}` is a variable. There are 1000 tables which I would like to run the same script in parallel.

How can I do that. please can anyone explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oozie doesnot support cyclic operation i.e you cannot call same action multiple times in a loop.

There are multiple ways to your task. I would suggest the below :

1. Create a property file with all 1000 tables.
2. Either have a shell script or java code to generate the sqoop query above by replacing the $table for each table in the property file. i.e you will end up with 1000 sqoop executable query.

Now that you have a shell script or java code that dynamically generates and executes sqoop commands, you could create single shell action or a java action  to execute your job via oozie.

Also, Running too many sqoop jobs in parallel might use up your JVM's RAM and has performance impact.

Comment: @K S Nidhin I have put all the 1000 tables in a file. This file I will pass as an argument. Now In which file should all the variables in the above query should be present